# How to get my APK signing certificate recognized by Android without uploading APK to PlayStore?

Tags: android, google-play, apk, keytool

I want to sign an Android APK for personal/internal use, which will not be uploaded to Play Store. When I try to install my app, even if "**Install from Unknown sources**" is enabled Google Play Protect shows a further warning which says "**Play Protect doesn't recognize this app's developer**". I am able to proceed by clicking "Install anyway".

However there are open source apps, not available in the Play Store, which can be downloaded directly from Github. For those APKs I don't get that extra warning if "Install from Unknown Sources" is enabled, which suggests that Google Play Protect already recognize the certificate they used to sign those APKs.

How do I achieve the same for an app that I don't want to upload to Play Store?

For signing I created a keystore using the `keytool` and added it to the `signingConfigs` section of the `build.gradle` file and the APK gets automatically signed during the release build.

Comment: Are you registered as an Android Developer? Meaning do you have a Play Console developer account?

Comment: @Loudenvier yes I have a registred Play Console account, but I have never published an App before

Comment: Publish the app in a closed track, this way you can add specific users to test it (including yourself). And you'll get the benefits of getting acquainted with the convoluted process of app publishing employed by Play Console (one that is ever changing :-) ). I believe that if the app is published once, google will be able to link it to your developer account and get rid of the second warning.